# Getting undefined in response when calling google cloud onCall Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I wrote 2 similar function, one is onRequest and other is onCall (as mentioned in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable))

## functions/index.js

```
const products = [];
const LIMIT = 100;
for (let i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
    products.push({
        name: "product" + i,
        price: "price" + i,
    });
}

exports.products1 = functions.https.onCall((input, context) => {
    const { page = 1, limit = 10 } = input;

    const startAt = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endAt = startAt + limit;

    return products.slice(startAt, endAt);
});

exports.products2 = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const { page = 1, limit = 10 } = request.query;

    const startAt = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endAt = startAt + limit;

    return response.json(products.slice(startAt, endAt));
});
```

I am able to call onRequest http function from command line using curl, but when I try to call onCall function from the app code (I am building on react-native and using firebase mobile number authentication), I am getting undefined in response.

## App.js

```
async fetchProducts() {
        const instance = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('products1');
        try {
            const response = await instance({
                page: 1,
                limit: 15,
            })
                .then(res => console.warn('Res',res))
                .catch(err => console.warn('Error', err));
            console.warn('Response', response);
        } catch (httpsError) {
            console.log('Message', httpsError.message);

            // Check code
            if (httpsError.code === firebase.functions.HttpsErrorCode.NOT_FOUND) {
                console.error('Functions endpoint "order" not found');
            }
        }
    };
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you examined the documentation for the protocol for callable functions?  They can't be treated just like normal HTTP functions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference

Comment: I read it. This is written in documentation - 
Note: In JavaScript clients, these requests trigger a CORS OPTIONS preflight, because:

    application/json is not allowed. It must be text/plain or application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
    The Authorization header is not a CORS-safelisted request-header.
    Other headers are similarly not allowed.
But in onCall, there is no need to pass authorization header explicitly or is there?
Also I am new to both react-native and firebase.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using at the same time `async/await` and the `then()` method.

If you modify your code as follows, it will work:

```
async fetchProducts() {
        const instance = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('products1');
        try {
            const response = await instance({
                page: 1,
                limit: 15,
            })
            console.warn('Response', response);
        } catch (httpsError) {
            console.log('Message', httpsError.message);

            // Check code
            if (httpsError.code === firebase.functions.HttpsErrorCode.NOT_FOUND) {
                console.error('Functions endpoint "order" not found');
            }
        }
    };
```

As you will read in the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) you don't need at all to use `then()`:

> The `await` expression pauses the execution of the async function
>   (i.e. `httpsCallable('products1')`) and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the `async` function's execution and
>   evaluates as the resolved value.

Comment: @sumitsharma Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?